# Openmpi compiling error: mpicxx.h "expected identifier before numeric constant"

Tags: openmpi

I'm trying to compile a program with openmpi, my code does not give any errors but instead one of the mpi headers does:

```
/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64/openmpi/ompi/mpi/cxx/mpicxx.h:168: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64/openmpi/ompi/mpi/cxx/mpicxx.h:168: error: expected unqualified id before numeric constant
```

The relevant line of code in the header simply reads:

```
namespace MPI {
```

I am using the mpiCC compiler. Am I doing something wrong? or is this a bug in openmpi?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to compile C++ code with the C compiler wrapper?

Comment: How did you get Open MPI installed?

Comment: Could you also please post the output of `mpiCC -showme`.

Comment: I installed OpenMPI through the add/remove software manager in Scientific Linux. 

@Hristo Output of mpiCC -showme: g++ -I/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64 -pthread -m64 -L/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib -lmpi_cxx -lmpi -lopen-rte -lopen-pal -ldl -Wl,--export-dynamic -lnsl -lutil -lm -ldl

Comment: Then it looks like your C++ compiler is treating your code as C code, not as C++. What is the extension of the file? Is it `.cpp` or `.C` or `.cc` or `.cxx` or `.c++` or is it just `.c`?

Comment: The extension of the file is .cpp

Comment: A wild guess: something is wrong with your C++ compiler.  Try compiling a trivial C++ program that simply contains "namespace testme { int foo; }" and see if it also chokes on the keyword "namespace".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am not able to reproduce the problem you encountered, the following comments can be found in `mpi.h`, from which `mpicxx.h` is included:

```
/*                                                                             
 * Conditional MPI 2 C++ bindings support.  Include if:
 *   - The user does not explicitly request us to skip it (when a C++ compiler
 *       is used to compile C code).
 *   - We want C++ bindings support
 *   - We are not building OMPI itself
 *   - We are using a C++ compiler
 */
#if !defined(OMPI_SKIP_MPICXX) && OMPI_WANT_CXX_BINDINGS && !OMPI_BUILDING
#if defined(__cplusplus) || defined(c_plusplus) 
#include "openmpi/ompi/mpi/cxx/mpicxx.h"
#endif
#endif
```

If you are not using the deprecated C++ bindings, then a possible workaround is to add

```
-DOMPI_SKIP_MPICXX
```

to your `CXXFLAGS`. Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I passed `-DMPI` to the compiler, which conflicts with `namespace MPI`.

Using `-DMPI=MPI` fixed the error.

In CMake:

```
target_compile_definitions(obj_mpi PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C,CXX>:MPI=MPI>)
```